# Передача аргумента

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Делаю небольшую вебморду для управления своим VPN сервером на Flask'е, с js знаком лишь слегка и битый час пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы можно было передать id элемента на который был клик (есть таблица, через кнопку можно удалять строки, отправив post запрос на сервер с id элемента, пред этим вылетает модальное окно для подтверждения действия)

```js
function confirmModal(callback){

    $('#ConfirmModal').modal('show');

    $('#ConfirmModal-no').on('click',  function () {
        callback(false);
        $('#ConfirmModal').modal('hide');
    });

    $('#ConfirmModal-ok').on('click',  function () {
        callback(true);
        $('#ConfirmModal').modal('hide');
    });
}


function send_request(some_id){
    $.post('/remove_user', {'user_target': some_id});
}


$('.confirm_remove').on("click", function () {
    var caller_id = this.id;
    confirmModal(function (result) {
        if (result){
            send_request(caller_id)
        }
    })
});
```

Собственно, я перепробовал много вариаций, но так и не понял каким костылем можно передать caller_id функции send_request, не прибегая к глобальным переменным.

**UPD:**
Все-таки сумел передать аргумент + избавился от дублирования обработчиков (спасибо за замечание от [Anton Shchyrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/221228/anton-shchyrov)) с помощью .one()

```js
function confirmModal(callback, id){

    $('#ConfirmModal').modal('show');

    $('#ConfirmModal-no').one('click',  function () {
        callback(false, id);
        $('#ConfirmModal').modal('hide');
    });

    $('#ConfirmModal-ok').one('click',  function () {
        callback(true, id);
        $('#ConfirmModal').modal('hide');
    });
}


function send_request(some_id){
    $.post('/remove_user', {'user_target': some_id});
}


$('.confirm_remove').on("click", function () {
    var caller_id = this.id;
    confirmModal(function (result, id) {
        if (result){
            send_request(id)
        }
    }, caller_id)
});
```

Comment: `one` использовать нельзя. Такой обработчик открепляется **после** срабатывания. Откройте модальное окно, нажмите отмену, а затем откройте окно на новом элементе. И посмотрите  сколько раз будет вызван `send_request`

Comment: Да, и правда, тогда что в таком случае делать? Делать `off` в начале функции?

Comment: Чем не устраивает передача id через `data`?

Comment: Не уверен, что понимаю как это применить, с `off` лишних телодвижений совершать не надо, но это, конечно, костыли

Comment: Посмотрите в моем ответе

Comment: Ох, огромное спасибо, извиняюсь, что отнял столько времени

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в функции `confirmModal` при каждом вызове добавляете по одному обработчику для кнопок. В итоге, когда окно закрывается, у вас вызываются все навешенные обработчики со своими id.

Я не знаю, что это за метод `modal` и нужно смотреть документацию по нему, как через него передать данные. Как вариант, использовать `$("#ConfirmModal").data()`

```js
function confirmModal(id) {
  $('#ConfirmModal').data({id: id}).modal('show');
}

$('#ConfirmModal-no').on('click', function() {
  $('#ConfirmModal').modal('hide');
});

$('#ConfirmModal-ok').on('click', function() {
  $('#ConfirmModal').modal('hide');
  const id = $('#ConfirmModal').data('id');
  send_request(id);
});

function send_request(some_id) {
  $.post('/remove_user', {'user_target': some_id});
}

$('.confirm_remove').on("click", function() {
  confirmModal(this.id)
});
```